# Best way to translate "apply my knowledge to solve real world problems"

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate this sentence `I want to apply my knowledge to solve real world problems`, and as far as I can think, I got this translation in my mind `我想用我的知識來解決現實世界的問題`, but I don't know if the translation is weird or if there is a better translation. Asking you guys for help, thanks!

Comment: nothing wrong with the translation

Comment: It is absolutely correct, but I suppose you to add a "中" between "世界" and "问题".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be translated as 学以致用.

学以致用 or 學以致用 is a Chinese idiom which means to study something in order to apply it. It probably comes from `《论语 子张》`.

The original text is

> 百工居肆以成其事，君子学以致其道

by English

> Workers toil and moil in the workshops to complete their job, while men of honor seek Tao by learning.

As for your sentence `I want to apply my knowledge to solve real world problems`, I can provide several translations for you to select from.

- 我想学以致用
- 我希望能（够）学以致用
- 我心怀学以致用的信念（梦想\理想）

Comment: This is beautiful! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I want to apply my knowledge to solve real world problems.
我想要将我的知识应用到解决实际问题中。

Comment: I think 'solve' in the original sentence is redundant and can be omitted in translation. Technically, your translation corresponds better to 'I want to apply my knowledge to solv*ing* real world problems.'